# Why is Dead Space 3 using the webcam?

Tags: origin, dead-space-3

Whenever I start up Dead Space 3 it starts using my webcam. I have checked all of the settings menus inside of the game as well as Origin (which I am running it through) and cannot find any settings that use either the webcam or its microphone. I am sure that this is the program using the webcam as the "in use" indicator light turns off if I minimize the game.

Where can I find the setting to disable this?

Comment: That's why I disable my webcam when it's not in use. Duct tape also helps.

Comment: That's....weird. Might have to do with Origin's Twitch streaming functionality though ? Maybe some errant code that activates it. Don't know myself, though.

Comment: How do you know it is using your webcam? Is there some sort of indicator on the cam itself or a software notification?

Comment: The indicator light on the webcam indicates that it is in use only when the game has focus. If the game loses focus, the indicator goes off, meaning it has something to do with the game and not simply a rogue application using it.

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of digging around it seems like the most likely option is that it is using your webcam for your microphone. There are no in-game options dealing with the microphone and there were pre-release reports that the engine would react to your own screams while playing. The mic is auto-on during co-op and the **only** mute function in the game relates to other players and is in the pre-game lobbies.

All of this leads me to believe that DS3 is accessing your webcam for its mic functionality and the camera's indicator does not differentiate between the mic/camera exclusively. This can be easily tested if there is a software setting to independently control the mic/camera.

As a caveat, I do not own DS3 nor do I game on PC, this question was just independently interesting and my answer is based purely on computer hardware/software knowledge and digging through the dregs of forum posts.

Comment: There is an order of magnitude more relevant search results with the terms "Dead Space 3 microphone" than "Dead Space 3 webcam", which this question is literally the only one relating.

Answer (score -1):

It is probably using it only because you cannot use the Kinect without the camera being on. The Kinect basically IS a webcam, and if you have it, it will use it.